SQL Query successfully executes through php script but does not update the database
like the title says, when executing my query through the php script it runs successfully, but does not update the database.
Executing the query directly in SSMS it works 100% and updates the record. It used to work but today it just stopped working, and I have no idea what could be causing the issue.
All columns in the database are VARCHAR values.  Below is the query and the PHP execution block
try {
    odbc_exec(CONNECTION, $SQL_ORDERS_INSERT);
    echo "LOCAL ORDERS ADDED<br><br>";
    odbc_free_result($ORDER_ADD);
catch (\Throwable $th) {
    echo $th->getMessage();
}

SQL query string is added to the variable $SQL_ORDERS_INSERT:
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT ORDER_NUMBER FROM dbo.ORDERS WHERE ORDER_NUMBER = 'ELD24-11-50') 
    INSERT INTO dbo.ORDERS (ORDER_NUMBER, TRANSACTION_TYPE, TRANSPORTER_CODE, SUPPLIER_CODE, SOURCE_CODE, CLIENT_CODE, 
    DESTINATION_CODE, ORDER_STATUS, ORDER_DATE, PRODUCT_CODE, TOTAL_WEIGHT, REMAINING, 
    COMMENT_DESCRIPTION_1, COMMENT_1, COMMENT_DESCRIPTION_2, COMMENT_2, COMMENT_DESCRIPTION_3, COMMENT_3, 
    REMAINING_TRUCKS, EMAIL_SENT, ORDER_SUCCESSOR, BARCODE_RECEIVING, SEAL_QUANTITY, SLIP_FIRST_WEIGH, TRUCKS_PER_DAY,
    NWP_SYNC) 
    VALUES ('ELD24-11-50', 'DISPATCHING', 'VRC', 'ELD', 'CHROME ', 'CHR', 
    'WB', 'ACTIVE', '2024-11-01 13:43', 'CHR001', '3100000', '-56400', 
    '', '', '', '', '', '', 
    '-1', '0', '', '0', '2', 'N/A', '999', '0') 
IF EXISTS (SELECT ORDER_NUMBER FROM dbo.ORDERS WHERE ORDER_NUMBER = 'ELD24-11-50') 
UPDATE dbo.ORDERS SET TRANSACTION_TYPE = 'DISPATCHING', 
                      TRANSPORTER_CODE = 'VRC', 
                         SUPPLIER_CODE = 'ELD', 
                           SOURCE_CODE = 'CHROME ', 
                           CLIENT_CODE = 'CHR', 
                      DESTINATION_CODE = 'WB', 
                          ORDER_STATUS = 'COMPLETE', 
                            ORDER_DATE = '2024-11-01 13:43', 
                          PRODUCT_CODE = 'CHR001', 
                          TOTAL_WEIGHT = '3100000', 
                             REMAINING = '-56400', 
                 COMMENT_DESCRIPTION_1 = '', 
                             COMMENT_1 = '',
                 COMMENT_DESCRIPTION_2 = '', 
                             COMMENT_2 = '', 
                COMMENT_DESCRIPTION_3 = '',
                            COMMENT_3 = '', 
                     REMAINING_TRUCKS = '-1', 
                           EMAIL_SENT = '0', 
                      ORDER_SUCCESSOR = '', 
                    BARCODE_RECEIVING = '0', 
                        SEAL_QUANTITY = '2', 
                     SLIP_FIRST_WEIGH = 'N/A', 
                       TRUCKS_PER_DAY = '999', 
                             NWP_SYNC = '1' 
WHERE ORDER_NUMBER = 'ELD24-11-50'



try catch won't work for odbc functions

Given that for some reason you tagged your question with sql-server, I am closing it with consistent dupe target. However, for odbc you obviously need to use odbc_error()

This is the first time I'm using Sql. I mainly use MySql, hence probably my lack of knowledge.
I looked at the question that says my question is a duplicate of, and it has nothing to do with what I've asked.

I hope you looked at other comments as well
